# Building an array containing Excel formulas

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm attempting to build a 33 X 954 array filled with the following Excel formulas:

```
firstcolumn = Table[StringJoin["=Knowledge!F", ToString[i]], {i, 2, 34}];

secondcolumn = Table[StringJoin["=Knowledge!F", ToString[i]], {i, 35, 67}];

thirdcolumn = Table[StringJoin["=Knowledge!F", ToString[i]], {i, 68, 100}];
```

i.e.; where r=33 and the indexes increase as follows: {i,(i1 + r),(i2 + r)}

until we get:

```
lastcolumn = Table[StringJoin["=Knowledge!F", ToString[i]], {i, 31451, 31483}];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Like this? `Transpose@Partition[
 StringJoin["=Knowlege!F", ToString@#] & /@ Range[2, 31483]
 , 33]`

Comment: Jesus that was fast! Thank you for your help N.J. Evans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're wanting all number from 2-31483 and the operation is the same for each number, it's probably best just to map a function over the range, then split it into sub-lists using `Partition`. If you want the result to run down the columns, you should apply `Transpose` at the end.

```
columns=StringJoin["=Knowlege!F", ToString@#] & /@ Range[2, 31483];
columns=Partition[columns,33];
columns=Transpose@columns
```

For illustration: 
`Partition[Range[9],3]` gives:`{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`
and 
`Transpose@Partition[Range[9],3]` gives:`{{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9}}`